# Integrating cos(x)/sqrt(x) between 0 and infinity to a user defined precision

Tags: c

So I'm trying to do what I've said above. The user will enter a precision, such as 3 decimal places, and then using the trapezium rule, the program will keep adding strips on until the 3rd decimal place is no longer changing, and then stop and print the answer.

I'm not sure of the best way to approach this. Due to the function being sinusoidal, one period of 2PI will almost be 0. I feel like this way would be the best way of approaching the problem, but no idea of how to go about it. At the moment I'm checking the y value for each x value to see when that becomes less than the required precision, however it never really goes lower enough. At x = 10 million, for example, y = -0.0002, which is still relatively large for such a large x value.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 1000000000; i++) 
{
    sumFirstAndLast += func(z);
    z += stripSize;
    count++;
    printf("%lf\n", func(z));
    if(fabs(func(z))<lowestAddition/stripSize){       
        break;                                      
    }                                                 
}
```

So this above is what I'm trying to do currently. Where `func` is the function. The `stripSize` is set to 0.01, just something relatively small to make the areas of the trapeziums more accurate. `sumFirstAndLast` is the sum of the first and last values, set at 0.001 and 1000000. Just a small value and a large value.

As I mentioned, I "think" the best way to do this, would be to check the value of the integral over every 2PI, but once again not sure how to go about this. My current method gives me the correct answer if I take the precision part out, but as soon as I try to put a precision in, it gives a completely wrong answer.

Comment: Are you going to integrate a sinusoudal function from 0 to infinity? The integral doesn't converge then, so there's no right answer. Do you know the function to be periodic? If so, do you know its period?

Comment: Yeah the function is periodic with a period of 2PI. WolframAlpha gives the answer to be sqrt(PI/2) between the limits of 0 and infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a non-periodic function that converges to zero you can (sort of) do a check of the function's value and compare to a minimum error value, but this doesn't work for a periodic function as you get an early exit before the integrand sum converges (as you've found out). For a non-periodic function you can simply check the change in the integrand sum on each iteration to a minimum error but that won't work here either.

Instead, you'll have to do like a few comments suggest to check for convergence relative to the period of the function, PI in this case (I found it works better than using 2*PI). To implement this do something like the following code (note I changed your sum to be the actual area instead of doing it at the end):

```
sumFirstAndLast = (0.5*func(a) + 0.5*func(b)) * stripSize;
double z = a + stripSize;
double CHECK_RANGE = 3.14159265359;
double NextCheck = CHECK_RANGE;
double LastCheckSum = 0;
double MinError = 0.0001;

for (int i = 1; i < 1000000000; i++) 
{
     sumFirstAndLast += func(z) * stripSize;

     if (z >= NextCheck)
     {
          if (fabs(LastCheckSum - sumFirstAndLast ) < MinError) break;
          NextCheck += CheckRange;
          LastCheckSum = sumFirstAndLast;
     }

     z += stripSize;
     count++;
}
```

This seems to work and give the result to the specified accuracy according to the value of `MinError`. There are probably other (better) ways to check for convergence when numerically integrating a periodic function. A quick Google search reveals [this paper](http://dip.sun.ac.za/~weideman/TW324/monthly021-036.pdf) for example.

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you so much! Honestly thought I'd never get this done!

Answer (score 1):

The integral of from 0 to infinity of cos(x)/sqrt(x), or sin(x)/sqrt(x) is well known to be sqrt(pi/2).   So evaluating pi to any number of digits is easier problem.  Newton did it by integrating a quarter circle to get the area = pi/4. The integrals are evaluated by the methods of complex analysis. They are done in may text books on the subject, and on one of my final exams in graduate school.

Comment: Yeah, but maybe he wants to use this specific method.

Comment: The function cos(x)/sqrt(x) is not periodic according to the mathematical definition of "periodic". So, the original poster is after all not evaluating the integral of a periodic function.

Comment: @juhist Yeah my mistake. The function is not actually "periodic" but it does repeat every 2PI, just with a different amplitude. What I was getting at is that if you could check the individual integrals over every 2PI, then they would almost be zero as the positive and negative parts would pretty much cancel each other out

Comment: No, they don't cancel each other out. I defined the function cos(x)/sqrt(x) and it's integral over [0,2*pi] is 1.2239, over [2*pi,4*pi] is 0.018465, over [4*pi,6*pi] is 0.0049320, over [6*pi,8*pi] is 0.0021025 and over [8*pi,10*pi] is 0.0011165. So, you can approximate 1.2239 + 0.018465 + 0.0049320 + 0.0021025 + 0.0011165 = 1.2505 and sqrt(pi/2) is 1.2533 so we're close but not quite there yet. You're missing that the amplitude isn't discrete, it's continuous, ie. the negative part has smaller amplitude than the positive part.

Comment: @jushist sorry i meant, eventually the integral over 2PI will equal zero because of the positive and negative parts within the 2PI.